# Columns in a dataframe(header) replace the contents having special format_Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a excel sheet and the Columns header contains dynamic suffix like "s.FName", "g.LName", "Age", "Address" , "P.CAR", "S.Licsence" etc (about 100 of columns).

Problem is that, some of the columns does not have suffix. so If i use the below code that columns head is empty. I tried  **pathlib** as well but doesnt work.

```
dataset = pd.read_excel(fileloc)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[1]
```

So is there any way i can put a condition in the 3rd line of code.
I also used the below code but giving error

```
dataset = pd.read_excel(fileloc)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
colindex = 0
for (columnName, columndata) in df.iteritems():
    if str(columnName).__contains__('.'):
        df.insert(colindex,str(columnName[0]).split('.')[1],columndata.value,True)
    else:
        df.insert(colindex, str(columnName[0]).split('.')[0],columndata.value,True)
```

Comment: have you tryed `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[-1]`?

Comment: Will try that for sure

Comment: Index(['1', '2', '3', nan, '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], dtype='object') This is the value I am getting while using your  solution @SergFSM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the optimal solution or the correct way to do this but other solution are always welcome.

```py
collist =[]
dataset = pd.read_excel(fileloc)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
#df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[-1]
for col in (dataset.head(0)):
    if str(col).__contains__('.'):

        ncol = str(col).split('.')[1]
        collist.append(str(ncol))
        #df.rename(columns={col: ncol for col, ncol in zip(col, ncol)}, inplace=True)
    else:
        ncol = str(col)
        collist.append(str(ncol))
        #df.rename(columns={col: ncol for col, ncol in zip(str(col), ncol)}, inplace=True)

col_rename_dict = {i: j for i, j in zip(dataset.head(0), collist)}
df.rename(columns=col_rename_dict, inplace=True)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71485503/2) to the question [Columns in a dataframe(header) replace the contents having special format_Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485503/columns-in-a-dataframeheader-replace-the-contents-having-special-format-python) by the OP [nishit dey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7747433/nishit-dey) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>